# Javascript array in loop

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to loop through all elements in an xml file with the name "playerhash" with javascript.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  
    alert(i);  
    if(getCookie('riskinfo') == xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("playerhash"[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {  
        player = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("playerhash")[i].getAttribute('color');  
        break;  
    }  
}
```

When I try to run the js it gives me `Line 3: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined` With the alert() function I figured out that the error is occurring when i = 0 and I know that there are at least four playerhash elements.
How can I loop through all of the elements without the error?

Comment: That means one or more of the playerhash has no children. Either add some more checking or make sure they all have children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deceze said, you have errors in the code. You should write your code in much smaller steps so that it is easier to debug. Also, check each step before proceeding so that if it fails unexpectedly, it will not throw errors at the user. Condition expresssions should not do assignment as that makes debugging more difficult, use them just for testing conditions:

```
// Should have already checked that xmldoc is a valid document

var riskinfo = getCookie('riskinfo');
var playerhash = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("playerhash");
var max = 4;  // or playerhash.length
var node, player;

for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {  
  node = playerhash[i];

  if (node && node.nodeValue == riskinfo) {
    player = node.getAttribute('color');
    i = max; // break out of for loop
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the coding tips. I'm pretty new to javascript and xml so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is always a good idea to keep statements brief and simple if possible. While it's more code, it does not affect speed (often it's faster) and the easier it is to understand, the easier it is to debug and maintain. Often the least experienced programmers are put onto maintenance, so make their life bearable. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.getElementsByTagName("playerhash"[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

You're missing a `)` in there. Should be something along the lines of this:

```
if (getCookie('riskinfo') == xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("playerhash")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {
```

Of course, repeating `xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("playerhash")` in every loop is rather expensive, you should do this once before the loop and save the result in a variable.

You should probably also check whether the `i`th element actually exists and whether it actually has any child nodes before trying to access that child node.